# When can $\textbf{SpecMax}(R)$ be a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes, affine-schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $(\text{Spec(R)},\mathcal{O}_R)$ be the affine scheme associated to $R$.

Let $\text{SpecMax}(R)$ the subspace the $\text{Spec(R)}$ of the maximal ideals.

My question is if there exists any conditions on $R$ such that $\text{SpecMax(R)}$ have strucutre of a scheme?

Thanks

Comment: If $R$ is Artinian then $\operatorname{Spec}(R) = \operatorname{SpecMax}(R)$.

Comment: @Geoff, But in general $SpeMax$ is considered like a subspace right ? not with a structure of locally ringed space. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it to be an affine scheme? In $\mathrm{SpecMax}(R)$ every point is closed. This means that you are looking for a $0$-dimensional ring associated to $R$. The only thing I remember right now is the Von Neumann regular quotient (but the name might be different).

Comment: Personally, I find giving an answer to this seems difficult because you haven't really given any condition of the structure sheaf. Do you want to define a structure sheaf on SpecMax($R$) so that there is a 'natural' immersion into Spec($R$)? Or do you not really care about its relation to Spec($R$)?